# Adding a d3 pie chart to banana

Tags: javascript, angularjs, solr, banana

I am new to solr and banana. I'm trying to add a pie chart to the banana dashboard. The panel get loads but the chart does not comes. Can some one please help me on this? I have created the module.html and also the *editor.html* files. When I debug the *module.js* file I found that the `var pie` variable is not executing.

I have added the modulejs file of the pie chart.

```
define(['angular', 'app', 'underscore', 'jquery', 'kbn', 'd3', './d3.tip'], function(angular, app, _, $, kbn, d3, d3tip) {
   'use strict';
   var module = angular.module('kibana.panels.pie', []);
   app.useModule(module);
   module.controller('pie', function($scope, querySrv, dashboard, filterSrv) {
      $scope.panelMeta = {
         modals: [{
            description: "Inspect",
            icon: "icon-info-sign",
            partial: "app/partials/inspector.html",
            show: $scope.panel.spyable
         }],
         editorTabs: [{
            title: 'Queries',
            src: 'app/partials/querySelect.html'
         }],
         status: "Experimental",
         description: "Display the D3 Pie Chart with Tooltip."
      };
      // Set and populate defaults
      var _d = {
         queries: {
            mode: 'all',
            query: '*:*',
            custom: ''
         },
         field: '',
         size: 10,
         spyable: true,
         show_queries: true,
         error: '',
      };
      _.defaults($scope.panel, _d);
      $scope.init = function() {
         $scope.hits = 0;
         $scope.$on('refresh', function() {
            $scope.get_data();
         });
         $scope.get_data();
      };
      $scope.get_data = function() {
         // Make sure we have everything for the request to complete
         if (dashboard.indices.length === 0) {
            return;
         }
         delete $scope.panel.error;
         $scope.panelMeta.loading = true;
         var request, results;
         $scope.sjs.client.server(dashboard.current.solr.server + dashboard.current.solr.core_name);
         request = $scope.sjs.Request().indices(dashboard.indices);
         $scope.panel.queries.ids = querySrv.idsByMode($scope.panel.queries);
         // Populate the inspector panel
         $scope.inspector = angular.toJson(JSON.parse(request.toString()), true);
         // Build Solr query
         var fq = '';
         if (filterSrv.getSolrFq() && filterSrv.getSolrFq() !== '') {
            fq = '&' + filterSrv.getSolrFq();
         }
         var wt_json = '&wt=json';
         var rows_limit = '&rows=0'; // for terms, we do not need the actual response doc, so set rows=0
         var facet = '&facet=true&facet.field=' + $scope.panel.field + '&facet.limit=' + $scope.panel.size;
         // Set the panel's query
         $scope.panel.queries.query = querySrv.getORquery() + wt_json + rows_limit + fq + facet;
         // Set the additional custom query
         if ($scope.panel.queries.custom != null) {
            request = request.setQuery($scope.panel.queries.query + $scope.panel.queries.custom);
         } else {
            request = request.setQuery($scope.panel.queries.query);
         }
         results = request.doSearch();
         // Populate scope when we have results
         results.then(function(results) {
            // Check for error and abort if found
            if (!(_.isUndefined(results.error))) {
               $scope.panel.error = $scope.parse_error(results.error.msg);
               return;
            }
            var sum = 0;
            var missing = 0;
            $scope.panelMeta.loading = false;
            $scope.hits = results.response.numFound;
            $scope.data = [];
            $scope.maxRatio = 0;
            $scope.yaxis_min = 0;
            _.each(results.facet_counts.facet_fields, function(v) {
               for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                  var term = v[i];
                  i++;
                  var count = v[i];
                  sum += count;
                  if (term === null) {
                     missing = count;
                  } else {
                     // if count = 0, do not add it to the chart, just skip it
                     if (count === 0) {
                        continue;
                     }
                     var slice = {
                        letter: term,
                        frequency: count
                     };
                     if (count / $scope.hits > $scope.maxRatio) {
                        $scope.maxRatio = count / $scope.hits;
                     }
                     $scope.data.push(slice);
                  }
               }
            });
            $scope.$emit('render');
         });
      };
      $scope.build_search = function(word) {
         if (word) {
            filterSrv.set({
               type: 'terms',
               field: $scope.panel.field,
               value: word,
               mandate: 'must'
            });
         } else {
            return;
         }
         dashboard.refresh();
      };
      $scope.set_refresh = function(state) {
         $scope.refresh = state;
         // if 'count' mode is selected, set decimal_points to zero automatically.
         if ($scope.panel.mode === 'count') {
            $scope.panel.decimal_points = 0;
         }
      };
      $scope.close_edit = function() {
         if ($scope.refresh) {
            $scope.get_data();
         }
         $scope.refresh = false;
         $scope.$emit('render');
      };
   });
   module.directive('pieChart', function() {
      return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function(scope, element) {
            // Receive render events
            scope.$on('render', function() {
               render_panel();
            });
            // Re-render if the window is resized
            angular.element(window).bind('resize', function() {
               render_panel();
            });
            // Function for rendering panel
            function render_panel() {
               element.html("");
               var width = element.parent().width();
               var height = parseInt(scope.row.height);
               var margin = {
                  top: 40,
                  right: 20,
                  bottom: 60,
                  left: 40
               };
               width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
               height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
               var formatPercent = d3.format(".0");
               var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).attr('style', 'background-color:red').append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
               var tip = d3tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').offset([-10, 0]).html(function(d) {
                  return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
               });
               var z;
               for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
                  alert("fr" + scope.data[z].frequency);
                  alert("lett" + scope.data[z].letter);
               }
               svg.call(tip);
               var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
               var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
               var color = ['#F2D7D5', '#E8DAEF', '#F1948A', '#E59866', '#EAEDED', '#2ECC71', '#5DADE2', '#CD6155'];
               var pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
                  return d.frequency;
               });
               alert("after");
               var path = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
               var label = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 40).innerRadius(radius - 40);
               var arc = g.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(scope.data)).enter().append("g").attr("class", "arc");
               arc.append("path").attr("d", path).attr("fill", function(d) {
                  return color(d.letter);
               });
               arc.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
               }).attr("dy", "0.35em").text(function(d) {
                  return d.letter;
               });
            }
         }
      };
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a *minimal* example?

Comment: Hi jens, mininmal example of the code or of the output?

Comment: You may need to use `d3.layout.pie()` instead of `d3.pie()`

Comment: yeah, you are correct Aadel. Thanks alot. :)